# Config в C#

Tags: c#

Есть конфиг, простой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings configSource="set.config">
    <add key="SetHost" value="havana" />
    <add key="SetDBName" value="ishop_janpizza" />
    <add key="SetPassword" value="12345" />
    <add key="SetUserDB" value="RemoteDBHavana" />
    <add key="SetRefleshTime" value="10" />
    <add key="SetConnect" value="30" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

пробую достать

```
string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SetUserDB"];
```

а переменная `а` пустая, что не так сделал?

Answer (score 1):

В строке конфига

```
<appSettings configSource="set.config">
```

нужно удалить configSource="set.config", т.к. этот атрибут заставляет считывать секцию целиком из файла set.config.